# Copy byte array directly into clipboard in Java

Tags: java, arrays, byte, clipboard

Is there any workaround to directly copy byte[] into clipboard.

The following code works fine for String.

```
String str = "My - String";
StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(str);
Clipboard clpbrd = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
clpbrd.setContents(stringSelection, null);
```

The reason is my byte[] is lengthy and it will take memory and time to convert it into String, as if I use **new String(bArray)** etc before copying it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a [`DataHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/activation/DataHandler.html):

```
DataHandler dataHandler = new DataHandler(bytes, "application/octet-stream");
clpbrd.setContents(dataHandler, null);
```

DataHandler is even capable of handling input streams, so you might not need the byte array at all.

Comment: Thanks, and also how may I get the array back then?

Comment: `((DataHandler)clpbrd.getContents(null)).getContent()` will return the byte array.

Comment: Will this work, too? byte[] data = (byte[]) clipboard.getData(new DataFlavor("application/octet-stream"));

Comment: I assumed so, given that it has been accepted. You're welcome!